# C++, calling a non-member function from a member function

Tags: c++

It is possible somehow to a call a non-member function from a member function?

Something like this:

```
class A {
    int a;
public:
    bool (int b) { 
       smt; 
       lala = define_smt(smt);
       if (lala < 5) {
           return true;
       }
       else {return false}
    }
}

int define_smt(smt){ ...}
```

Thnaks in advance

Comment: Yes. (20 more characters)

Comment: Assuming that the declaration of `define_smt` appears before the first usage, then yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function must be known at call time. That means you must declare it before you use it. You have basically two choices here: Either put the whole function before the class, or use a function prototype before the class. So either:

```
int define_smt(smt) { ... }

class A {
    // ...
}
```

or:

```
int define_smt(smt);

class A {
    // ...
}

int define_smt(smt) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course It is Possible. As long as your function is available in the current context. i.e. either **a prototype or a defination should be available, before the point of calling**.